# Find By Id using Coffeescript and lodash

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, lodash

I have the following array:

```
@$.contacts = [
            id: "55a1191de4b0c27d36f972d0"
            name: 'Alice Freeman'
            avatar : 'http://avatars.jurko.net/pic/8488/'
        ,
            id: 1
            name: 'Danielle Obrien'
            avatar : 'http://avatars.jurko.net/pic/2944/'
        ,
            id: 2
            name: 'James Lewis'
            avatar : 'http://avatars.jurko.net/pic/14129/'
        ,
            id: 3
            name: 'Vincent Munoz'
            avatar : 'http://avatars.jurko.net/pic/19063/'
        ]
```

I would like to find and return based on the id using a lodash function like:

```
memberById:(member) ->
        mem = _.find @$.contacts, member.id
        return mem
```

How do I get the comparison to be using member.id ?

Comment: You mean `_.find @$.contacts, (c) -> c.id is member.id`?

Comment: Yes. That seems to be doing the trick! Would you like to create an answer with it so I can award it to you? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As given in a comment by @elclanrs, the best method is `_.find`. As per the [docs](http://devdocs.io/lodash~4/index#find), find can be passed a function, object or string.

With the function:

```
_.find @$.contacts, (c) -> c.id is member.id
```

Or you can pass it an object fragment to match:

```
_.find @$.contacts, id: member.id
```